# I cannot use Google Tag Manager, dataLayer push doesn't reflect anything on Analytics event panel

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

GTM snippet put after the GAnalytics one:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
      }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

So I'm trying to run on console (from localhost, I tried also on live)

`dataLayer.push({'event':'test'});`

then when I look ad the Analytics event panel (real time) nothing appears on the graph. Any suggestion or idea why that's happening?

Comment: Could you please share more details with us? What are your GTM settings regarding Universal Analytics? Where do you provide the event details (category, action, label), that should be sent into Analytics?

Comment: `dataLayer.push({'event':'test'});` wont sent any data to GA

Comment: Actually, I didn't set anything on GTM, I'm trying to understand how to trigger an Analytics event anytime I push something into dataLayer array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By default, Google Tag Manager doesn't send any data anywhere**. When you do a `dataLayer.push` call, data is simply added to the `dataLayer` which sits in the client's browser.

**For GTM to send data**, you need to configure triggers and tags. If you want to setup GTM as passthrough so it sends whatever data you push to it to Google Analytics, here is an example:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/create-a-generic-event-tag/

Some general info about GTM:

- `Variables`: they allow you to fetch data from the dataLayer
- `Triggers`: they are rules that define when certain tags should be fired
- `Tags`: they are pieces of code that can do whatever you want (add a banner to your website, send data to Google Analytics etc...).

Answer (score 1):

> dataLayer.push({'event':'test'});

It sends data to dataLayer, not to GA.
You can then create a GA Tag with trigger type "Custom event" using name of your event.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out firing event straight from gtag (Google Analytics):

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  event_category: <category>,
  event_label: <label>,
  value: <value>
});
```

Comment: This is the one you want to use if you want to send data immediately to Analytics.  Also you can add 'event_callback' to find out when the data has been sent. More info here:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events  and here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data